# Amplify Hosting Env build fails on npm install

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Im working on a project and pushed manually to my amplify backend until now and set up an hosting env connected to my github branch. But I receive the following error when the build starts via github:

```
2024-01-17T14:53:56.459Z [INFO]:  Received error [Error: Command failed with ENOENT: npm.cmd install --no-bin-links --production spawn npm.cmd ENOENT] running command [npm.cmd install --no-bin-links --production]
```

These are my build settings:

```
version: 1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

and set the Amplify CLI to 12.10.1.

Answer (score 0):

If you are pushing the backend manually, I presume you can be without the backend `amplifypush --simple`. Try this `build.yml`:

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm i
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: dist
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

If this does not work, I would try omitting the cache part.

Comment: I manually pushed until now, but wanted auto-deploy to work from now on. Sadly removing the cache part didn't work :(

Comment: I think sharing your package.json could help. You could diagnose the versions AWS Amplify supports. Secondly, you could see whether you're doing a full CI/CD build, or just the front-end. Lastly, you could check your cloudformation to see which stack is failing.